# How to write an XSL 1.0 stylesheet with a node-set() function that will run on both MSXML and libxml

Tags: msxml, xslt-1.0, libxml2

I have an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet running using the XSL processor included with PHP (libxml). I want to get the same stylesheet to run on the Microsoft XSL processor MSXML 6.0 (msxml6.dll) ideally so the same stylesheet can run on either processor.

Unfortunately at the moment I would need to have two stylesheets - one for each processor.

This snippet invokes the node-set() function on the PHP processor;

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="rtf">
            <a>hello</a><b>world</b>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="ns" select="exsl:node-set($rtf)"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$ns/b"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This snippet invokes the node-set() function on the Microsoft processor;

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  extension-element-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="rtf">
            <a>hello</a><b>world</b>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="ns" select="msxsl:node-set($rtf)"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$ns/b"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

If the input document was;

```
<root/>
```

The result of both stylesheets would be;

```
<b>world</b>
```

I want a single stylesheet that can run unchanged on the PHP processor and the Microsoft processor.

Although my real stylesheet is about 400 lines long and the the node-set() function is used in four places, I hope the examples above demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked on libxml and msxsl, works in both cases.

Regards

Mike.

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl func msxsl"
  >

    <func:function name="msxsl:node-set">
      <xsl:param name="node"/>
      <func:result select="exsl:node-set($node)"/>
    </func:function>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="rtf">
            <a>hello</a><b>world</b>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="ns" select="msxsl:node-set($rtf)"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$ns/b"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```